# Is there any wildcard character for awk FS?

Tags: awk

Is there any wildcard character for awk FS? In my awk script, I can’t print the values with “^R” separators (I don’t know what type of character is this). On the other hand, it can print those with FS=”*” and others.
Like below,

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="*"; i=0; ORS=""}
but it can’t do with
awk 'BEGIN {FS="^R"; i=0; ORS=""}
```

Would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2):

^R is octal 022 or hex 12.  It is the ASCII DC2 (device control 2) character.

#### Octal

In `awk`, use `\022` to match ^R as a field separator:

```
$ echo $'one\022two\022three' 
onetwothree
$ echo $'one\022two\022three' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\022"; i=0; ORS=""} {printf "1=%s; 2=%s; 3=%s\n",$1,$2,$3}'
1=one; 2=two; 3=three
```

#### Regular Expression

It is possible to use regular expressions for field separators.  In regular expressions, as opposed to shell globs, the period is the wildcard:

```
$ echo $'one\022two\022three' | awk -F'.t' '{printf "1=%s; 2=%s; 3=%s\n",$1,$2,$3}'
1=one; 2=wo; 3=hree
```

Here, the period (wildcard) in `.t` happens to match the ^R.

#### Hexadecimal

`awk` also supports hex notation:

```
$ echo $'one\022two\022three' | awk -c -F'\x12' '{printf "1=%s; 2=%s; 3=%s\n",$1,$2,$3}'
1=one; 2=two; 3=three
```